# What are the advantages of the different built-in image abstractions?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, drawing, imagesource

In my application I want to show small images at different places.

I use different Built-In Types to represent those images, but
I'm curious whether there is a single "best of all" representation.

For context:

Those images are composed from parts that are stored in a database.

At the moment I use `ImageSource` here, together with `Drawing` for
composing the Images.

For getting those images to the UI, I use an `Image` with Source set
to the overall `ImageSource` that comes from the ImageComposition
(which is doing the Database related stuff and sets together the
"overall" image). This `Image` is then pushed into a `ContentControl`.
Those images appear on different locations in the application and
they need to be scaled to fit in those locations.

As i have all source code available and can change it as i like:

**What is the abstraction to use with the most advantages?** (UI Rendering <==>
rendering in the application for example).

Possible are at the moment: `ImageSource`, `Image`, `Drawing` or even `Control`.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment you are doing at least two image processing operations:

- [image translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28geometry%29)
- [image scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling)

What if in the near future you will need to do some other image processing tasks - such as image contrast adjustment or maybe you will need to rotate images a bit ?

So the point is that .NET doesn't have integrated solution for image processing tasks.
I would better recommend to integrate image processing .NET library such as [ImageMagic.Net](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/), because it is the right tool for the job at hand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The image processing is not the main problem. But i think that the different ways to tackle such a problem all have their very own disadvantages. I believe when I use a Drawing, the whole rendering of the image will be done very late by the WPF UI, meaning it is hardware accelerated and probably runs on the graphics card. But I'm not sure, as I am quite new to graphics in Dot Net.